# SwiftUI painting problem with list rows outside the visible viewport

Tags: swiftui

I try to implement a SwiftUI app like this example by Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces

However, there is a problem with rows they are initialy outsite of the viewport. Theses rows are not painted.

You can reproduce the problem if you download the project file of Apples example and open the complete example project. Than change in the Home.swift on line 38 the frame height to 800 so that the rows are outsite of the viewport.

The result is this:

[image: Screenshot]

I’m new in SwiftUI and I have no idea why the rows are not rendered. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see any issues.

Comment: The issue is that the row Mountains and Rivers are empty and the rows and items will not painted. It's a huge issue. This is the expected result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax4o8sjcwanv97r/Screenshot%202019-12-08%2020.42.21.png?dl=0

Comment: I understand what you said. I just can't see that even when I changed line 38 to `800`.

Comment: This is strange. I can see the painting problem in the Xcode preview, on the simulator and on an iPhone 11 Pro Max. The problem also occurs in my own derived project.

Comment: Here is a [short video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ge9zjr5j4smrvx6/SwiftUI_repaint_bug.m4v?dl=0) to demonstrate the problem. It's better to see if line 42–45 `ForEach(categories.keys.sorted()…` is duplicated.

Comment: Also I found a solution that works for me. I use a `ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false)` with `VStack` instead of the `List`.